# Difference between $8 and 8 in GAS

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

So I've recently gotten into assembly programming and I've settled for the GNU Assembler for now. In GAS, you can define constant numbers using the syntax `$n` (where `n` is the number of course). However, because I did not know about this, I just assumed it would be okay to use the actual number (e.g `add 8, %esp` instead of `add $8, %esp`). As a result of this, my code showed dramatically different behaviour.

So my question is, what does the `$` actually do? I have no clue what could differentiate a "normal" number from a `$`'d one.

Comment: If you don't use the `$` it's a memory reference, technically a special case of the `displacement(%base, %index, scale)` full effective address, with only the `displacement` given.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!